# Filtering "bad" data from a pandas dataframe and plotting the "good" results

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working with a function that plots the light curves of various sources from two pandas data frames. I would like to write a loop to cycle through each light curve in the data frame that will plot the good light curves. The function works by plotting two curves on the same plot, one from each data frame. I need the loop to count the data points from one of the curves (the LSST curve) and eliminate plots that have less than 5 points. All of the HiTS plots have enough data points, but the LSST plots have had filters applied to them. I am still relatively new to Python so I am pretty confused about how to go about doing this. The function in question is listed below:

```
def plotLsstHitsLightCurve(obj, srcTable, row, lcPath='random file path'):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

    # Plot LSST curve
    srcRowFilter = (srcTable['diaObjectId'] == obj)
    srcRow = srcTable.loc[srcRowFilter]
    plt.errorbar(srcRow['midPointTai'], srcRow['magCol'],yerr=srcRow['magErrCol'],ls=':', marker='o', label='LSST')

    # PLot HiTS Curve
    tok = row['internalID'].split('_')
    field = '_'.join([tok[0],tok[1]])
    ccd = tok[2]
    lightcurveFile = field + '_' + ccd + '_LC_50.tar.gz'
    tarball = tarfile.open(os.path.join(lcPath,field,ccd,lightcurveFile))
    data = tarball.extractfile(str(row['internalID'])+ '_g.dat')
    dfl = pd.read_csv(data,sep='\t') # lead a file with a light curve data into a pandas dataframe
    plt.errorbar(dfl.MJD,dfl.MAG_AP1,dfl.MAGERR_AP1, marker='o',linestyle=':', label='HiTS')
obj = goodObj.iloc[idx[2]]['diaObjectId']
row = hitsDf.iloc[2]
```

```
enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: You probably won't be able to get a good answer from anyone without sharing at least a sample of your data.

Comment: just a small sample would be fine

Comment: The data is a massive pandas data frame with about 20 columns, so it's sort of difficult to give the data. I am only using a few columns, but there are still about 450,000 rows of data. Basically any data frame with random points would work for these purposes.